# Angular Setting a Fixed Value to a Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

In my code, I have a column where a user can add an element and select its priority type whilst adding the element. I'm trying to give that dropdown a default value (`row.PriorityType.Id ==1`). I tried to do it like below, but I got errors. Can I use the `value` property for my case? What should I fix?

**HTML:**

```
 <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" *ngIf="EditIndex == i" class="w-100-p">
     <mat-select [(ngModel)]="row.PriorityType" name="PriorityType" [(value)]="{row.PriorityType?.Id == 1}">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let priority of priorityList" [value]="priority">
            {{priority.Name}}
        </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust a couple of things:

- assigning both `ngModel` and `value` to your input will only cause trouble.
- these two `[(ngModel)]="row.PriorityType"`  and `[(value)]="{row.PriorityType?.Id == 1}"`, woulv d potentially be setting different values to the controller. (one being "row.PriorityType" the other a boolean)

The best option to assign/read form values is to use [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) in angular, my bottom line advice is for you to spend some time implementing it.

but if you'd like to just fix your code, please remove the `value` field from the template, and manipulate the value of the "row.PriorityType" data directly as required (which in turn is reflected into the template).

It should be enough to have the function which creates the new element (on the ".ts" side) setting the default value of "row.PriorityType" in your case.